My Flutter app is crashing in device immediately installing from Xcode 16.1. I have FCM setup and using Flutter 3.19.1 and dart Dart 3.3.0
My Flutter app is crashing in device immediately installing from Xcode 16.1  I have FCM setup and using Flutter 3.19.1 & dart Dart 3.3.0, and have added
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
in the podfile and imports are
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
did everything possible but couldn't find any solution to this It is crashing and immediately opens the seetings app.

What does the crash log say?

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
Dummy_UAT.debug.dylib                  0x1030e0014 __debug_main_executable_dylib_entry_point + 64
50  dyld                                  0x103001ce4 start + 519
Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_ke
